# How to get attribute from native View

Tags: java, android, layout, attr

**How can I get back an attribute from "native view"?**

I expanded `AppBarLayout` and in my XML layout, I use the attribute:

```
app:expanded="false"
```

**I know how to get an attribute from custom stylable, but how can I get it from a standard attribute?**

```
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ???? );
expanded = ta.getBoolean( ???? , false);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, but i'm not sure that it is a good way.

I defined a stylable and re-define the same name:

```
<declare-styleable name="attrs_global_boolean">
    <attr name="expanded" format="boolean"/>
    ....
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="AppBarLayout"> // here i use the same name of the original class, doesn't seem to give me any error, maybe it is better do use AppBarLayoutCustom or AppBarLayoutExtra (or any other name ?? )
    <attr name="expanded"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

And then

```
final static protected int[] STYLEABLE_AppBarLayout = R.styleable.AppBarLayout;
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, STYLEABLE_AppBarLayout );
expanded = ta.getBoolean( R.styleable.AppBarLayout_expanded, false);
ta.recycle();
```

Is there a way to get it whithout the need to re-define a stylable with the same attribute name ? a better way to do it ?

Thanks